# Stripe Ruby on Rails Sources API (Sofort) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and I'm trying to make Sofort Payment available. My charges controller looks like this:

```
def create
  source = Stripe::Source.create(
    :type => "sofort",
    :amount => 750,
    :currency => 'eur',
    :sofort => {
      :country => "AT"
    },
    :redirect => {
      :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/"
      }
  )
end
```

Log output when clicking the "Submit" button:

```
Rendering charges/create.html.erb within layouts/application
```

I'm expecting that the User will be redirected to his "Sofort" payment page, however the form just gets submitted and the create.html.erb is rendered.

Comment: This code simply creates a source but doesn't do anything else. There's no way for Rails to know that it should redirect. You have to explicitly handle the redirect yourself afterwards as documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sofort#customer-action

Comment: Ok thank you. So what I forgot was adding a redirect at the end: `redirect_to source["redirect"]["url"]`